# Имеет ли смысл хранить css и js-файлы на отдельных доменах?

Tags: javascript, css

Как известно, подгрузка css-стилей и JavaScript-кода со сторонних сервисов позволяет снизить размер сайта и тем самым увеличить быстродействие. Например, так:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Вопрос: можно ли добиться того же самого эффекта снижения размера сайта, если ещё и свои собственные стили и JS-код хранить в отдельном домене?

Например, вместо того, чтобы хранить стили в директории сайта на хостинге, как это обычно делают:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">
```

мы покупаем ещё один домен, туда загружаем только css- и js- (и ничего больше), и подключам в свой основной сайт:

```
<link href="domain-name.ru/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">
```

Вероятно, в особенности это будет иметь смысл, когда два разных сайта имеют общие стили.

Comment: Более того, каждый отдельный файл должен храниться на специально выделенном для него сервере.

Comment: Интересно... А можете конструктивно обосновать?

Comment: Выводится методом математической дедукции. Слышали от таком? Если что-то верно для двух случаев, то годится и для всех остальных. Разбросали по доменам скрипты и стили, получился ништяк. Значит, разбросав по доменам все файлы, получим ещё больше ништяков.

Comment: А если надо меньше ништяков, то двух серверов хватит? Ладно, на следующее Ваше сообщение отвечать не буду, а то могут отшлёпать за флуд.

Comment: Достаточно и одного сервера, кто-то уже и ответ написал правильный.

Comment: В век HTTP/2 это скорее вредно

Answer (score 3):

Если сайт с js и css содержимым будет недоступен на всех остальных сайтах вы получите битые страницы, плюс неудобство разработки и плюс заморочки с дополнительным доменом и хостингом. если вы считаете такие жертвы оправданными из за нескольких сотен килобайт то web технология позволяет сделать это и имеет право на существование.

Comment: Дополнительный хостинг не обязательно - главное, чтобы домены были разные. Некоторые хостинги предлагают услугу "мультидомен". Вот и можно в один домен-аккаунт погрузить некоторые css и js (ту же самую jquery или кросс-браузерные css-стили),  и подключать в другие сайты. Что скажете про этот частный случай?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu , а смысл тогда какой это делать если физическая файловая система одна и та же? никакого ускорения не будет, а вы будете километровые пути до своих файлов в коде прописывать. в чем удобство. А вот проблемы из за MX параметров домена могут привести к недоступности таких путей.

Comment: Допустим, Вы создали на каком-нибудь хостинге аккануты abc.com и xyz.com; у каждого своя доменная папка, у каждого свои стили и js-коды. Если я захожу на abc.com, то у меня вывод в браузер будет только из файлов папки abc.com, не затрагивая файлы из xyz.com, так? А теперь преставим, что abc.com и xyz.com используют одни и те же стили. Я создаю на том же хостинге ещё один домен common.com и загружаю в папку с этим доменом общие css-стили и подключаю их и в abc.com, и в xyz.com. Таким образом, нет нужды дублировать код на двух сайтах + каждый сайт весит меньше.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu , 1) js и css весят очень мало и покупать  (учитывайте и продление) домен из за 5 мегабайт не логично. 2) допустим у вас возникнет ситуация что стиль должен немного отличатся от основного, что вы будете делать? 3) то что не меняется время от времени и так доступно на головных хостингах (например библиотека jquery) 4) если бы ваш способ был так хорош как вы его представляете его все уже давно использовали, а все пользуются простым копированием файлов из одного места в другое.

проще говоря у вас не файловое хранилище и овчинка выделки не стоит.

Comment: 1) Согласен. 2) Переопределю стили поверх ранее определённых. 3) А что если я написал ряд JS-функций общего назначения и регулярно ими пользуюсь? Если я захочу их рефакторить, то на всех сайтах, где эти функции подключены, придётся тоже вставлять новый код. 4) Хорошо, первый недостаток - это необходимость покупать новый домен и продлевать его. У меня два вопроса: 1. Какие ещё есть недостатки? 2. При условии, что хостинг хороший, даст ли всё-таки хранение на выделенном домене стилей и js уменьшение объёма сайта и за счёт этого быстродействие?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu 1) недостатки я перечислил выше.
2) а вы представьте что оба сайта сейчас у вас на одном физическом диске сервера, сначала сервер считает css с первого сайта потом его головка поедет к картинке с второго сайта. и все это по запросу браузера (который заставит головку жёсткого диска летать туда сюда). т.е никакого прироста скорости попросту не будет.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu если начнете рефракторить то допущенная ошибка отразится на всех сайтах сразу

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49585/discussion-between-gurebu-bokofu-and-perfect).